# Google Active Script: using map in an array with 2 arguments

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, array-formulas, map-function

**This works:**

Suppose I want to use in an `ArrayFormula()` the `indirect()` function, which doesn't work. That is, supposed I type this in cell `E1`, `=ArrayFormula(indirect(address(row(E:E),column(A:A))))`, this will return the value of cell `A1` in all the cells in `column E`. To circumvent this, I created the custom function below:

```
function retValue(cell){
  if(cell.map) {
    return cell.map(retValue);
  } else {
    var cellRang = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange(cell);
    return cellRang.getValue();
  }
}
```

Now, when I enter this `=ArrayFormula(retValue(address(row(E:E),column(A:A))))` in cell `E1`, each cell in `column E` will have the corresponding value of the cell in the same row of `column A`.

**My problem:**

What I need is to have a custom function that receives 2 arguments, like `function retValue2(cell, anotherRange)` but I only care if `cell` is an array, as `anotherRange` must be an array anyway. What happens is that when I iteratively call `cell.map(retValue2)` the argument `anotherRange` is lost and I'm not entirely sure how to go about this.

I tried to come up with this:

```
function retValue2(cell, anotherRange) {
  if (cell.map) {
    return cell.map(retValue2);
  } else {
    var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange(anotherRange);
    var nrRows = range.getNumRows();
    var nrCols = range.getNumColumns();
    return cell + ',' + nrRows + ',' + nrCols;
  }
}
```

But it fails because `anotherRange` is not recognized inside the iteration I think. How do I solve this?

PS.: in the example that works, why exactly does it work at all? I understand that when I do this `return cell.map(retValue);` it will use my own function as the callback, which would return all the values in the array, but in the spreadsheet it shows only the one on the same row. What is the magic here?

**EDIT:**

My end goal is to create my own lookup function where I pass a search key and a 2-dimensional array (rows and columns) and then, it locates the coordinates of that key in the array.

Look here:

```
function retCoord(sKey, sIRange) {
  try {
    var key = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange(sKey).getValue();
  }
  catch(e) {
    var key = sKey;
  }
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange(sIRange).getValues();
  nbRow = range.length;
  nbColumn = range[0].length;
  for(var i = 0; i<nbRow; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j<nbColumn; j++){
      if(range[i][j] == key){
        return i + ", " + j;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If in my spreadsheet I enter something like `=retCoord("K4","A:L")` it will search the content of cell `K4` in my 2-dimensional array A:L and return where in the array the value is, `1, 2` for example. It also works if I use `=retCoord(K4,"A:L")` or `=retCoord("term searched","A:L")`, and in this latter case I enter directly the term searched. This works fine until I use it in an `ArrayFormula()`.

First, instead of `=retCoord("K4","A:L")` I could very well use `=retCoord(address(4, 11),"A:L")` for instance and my `.getRange()` method would get the cell `K4` just fine.

Now, here is the big problem. I want to use my function in an `ArrayFormula()`, and, positioning my cursor in `O1` and hoping to search the items from `column D` in the `columns E` through `L` I want to pass as one of the inputs of `address()`, `row(O:O)`, like this: `=ArrayFormula(retCoord(address(row(O:O),4,4),"E:L"))`, meaning that for each row, a new address is passed. that is, in `O1` cell, it should return the result of `retCoord(D1,"E:L")`, in `O2` should be `retCoord(D2,"E:L")`, in `O3` should be `retCoord(D3,"E:L")` and so on.

The issue happens because in my function, `sKey` is an array and if I try to use the same approach as my function `retValue` (here above in the **This works:** section) it fails because now, in `retCoord`, I have 2 inputs, and the introspection function calling from before fails because of the second input. Of course I'm missing something and there is always a better and more elegant way to approach a problem. But for now, can anyone help me with this one?

**EDIT2:**

I changed the code a little and it seems I moved forward but not quite yet. Check comment below for line indicated by (*):

```
function retCoord(sKey, sIRange) {
  var key = '';
  try {
    key = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange(sKey).getValue();
    return key;
  }
  catch(e) {
    if (sKey.map) {
      var objKey = sKey.map(retCoord);
      return objKey; // (*) <--- comments below
      key = objKey;
    } else {
      key = sKey;
    }
  }
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange(sIRange).getValues();
  nbRow = range.length;
  nbColumn = range[0].length;
  for(var i = 0; i<nbRow; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j<nbColumn; j++){
      if(range[i][j] == key){
        return key + " = "+ i + ", " + j;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This (*) line I added only to see what was returning from the map. Surprisingly (in a way), it is an object with all the elements of that column and that is expected. What I didn't expect was that if I return that object to my spreadsheet cell, it brings back only the value of that specific cell (as I wanted but not really as expected). But the problem is I cannot use that object to compare against a string as it will expand and become something else and will never match. Look:

1. If I do `return objKey` in my custom function, over cell O1 it returns "a", in O2 it returns
   "b", in O3 it returns "c" as expected because those are the values
   of my cells D1, D2, D3 respectively.
2. If I do `return "-> " + objKey`
   in in my custom function, instead of returning `-> a`, `-> b`, `-> c` in O1, O2, O3 respectively, it returns `-> =A:A,a,b,c,d,e,f` for all the cells in `column O`, which seems it did some type of `objKey.toString()` under the hood before concatenating with "-> "

Conclusion: how do I "coerce" the apparent result of `objKey` into string keeping the apparent result when you return the object without changing it? Simply put, I want the concatenation "some string" +  to be equal to "some string" + "one string representing the value in that row instead of an object". In other words, what the hell is happening here? How does Google Sheets now that in that row, that element is the one representing the one I want? This is what I asked in the "PS." in the first part of this post.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but wouldn't it be easier to use in E1 =Arrayformula(A:A) to show the contents of column A in column E ?

Comment: I believe that using Apps Script your issue can be solved in a more elegant way, without cell formulas. For this, could you explain a little bit more in detail what your general intention is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Supporting arrays in custom functions with multiple inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57363672/supporting-arrays-in-custom-functions-with-multiple-inputs)

Comment: @JPV, if I wanted to have just the value of the column A, yes. But that was ludic. Imagine that instead of A:A I wanted column(A:A)+1 (=B:B), or depending on some circustance, it would be column(A:A)+1, else column(A:A)+2, and so on and so forth. I will explain in my question what I used it for.

Comment: @ziganotschka, I will try to explain a little better in my question

Comment: @TheMaster, it is not. The link you pointed out is not for an "introspection" function in a map(), that shows a function created on the fly, like `.map(function (x) {return x*2;}`

Comment: Concept is still the same.  You need to practice arrays.

Comment: @TheMaster, it could be the case that I need to practice arrays, I'm not denying it. But this is not a duplicate of that question as you mentioned.

Comment: I provided in my question a full explanation of what is going on and a working "prototype" of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Could you tell the difference between what you call "introspection" function and a function created on a fly? Why do you think the approach provided there will be any different in your case? Notice how I pass a anonymous function to `map`, which calls the top function recursively with needed parameters? If you could solve the problem in the simplest sense(dumbed down version), You could always solve the same problem with complex variables, because, at it's core, nothing changed. I suggest you review my answer and references to understand it completely.

Comment: @TheMaster, in your example `function(xEl, i)` is a brand new function in your map and as you pointed out, `i` is the index in your map function. In my case, I don't use a brand new function, I call my own function iteractively (I heard somewhere that is called introspection). Because of that, my second argument `sIRange` is replaced with index, instead of keeping its old value. I "kinda" circumvented this, but hit another roadblock that may be simpler to solve. Can you check in the ** EDIT2 ** please?

Comment: *in your example function(xEl, i) is a brand new function in your map and as you pointed out, i*... *Because of that, my second argument sIRange is replaced with index,* Notice that `multiply` needs two unique numbers `x` and `y`- not a ``number``(`x`) and it's `index`(`i`). So, what does this  `function(xEl, i)` do? It calls the `multiply` function with xElement in the array `x` and for the second argument, finds the appropriate `y` element and calls `multiply` with appropriate `x` and `y`(or xElement and yElement).

Comment: Think of it like this: Instead of passing a single function(top function) to `map`, We pass a single function(which can only receive element and index), which calls the top function, which we can call it with any argument. We can call this latter single function a nested function.

Comment: Got it. I think I was trying to return one of the elements from the `map()` so I could return that one element to my spreadsheet. It turns out that for some reason, if you return the whole array to the spreadsheet Google identifies what is the element inside the array to be used, pretty sweet.

Comment: I don't know if I should answer my own question with the final code. It seems pretty lame :D

Answer (score 0):

You want to search all keys in the sKey column within the Range sIRange and note the position of each key within the range into the corresponding row in a destination column ?

### This is how you can do it with Apps Script without formulas:

```
function retCoord(sKeyColumn, destinationColumn, sIRange) {
  var key = sKeyColumn;
  var range=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange(sIRange);
  var rangeValues = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange(sIRange).getValues();
  var nbRow = rangeValues.length;
  var nbColumn = rangeValues[0].length;
  var sKeyRange=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange(sKeyColumn);
  var destinationRange=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange(destinationColumn);
  var sKeyValues=sKeyRange.getValues();
  for(var k=0;k<sKeyValues.length;k++){
    for(var i = 1; i<=nbRow; i++){
      for(var j = 1; j<=nbColumn; j++){
        if(range.getCell(i, j).getValue() == sKeyValues[k][0]){
          destinationRange.getCell(k+1, 1).setValue(range.getCell(i, j).getA1Notation());
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Sample call:

```
function myFunction(){
retCoord('A1:A6','B1:B6','C1:J7');
}
```

> `retCoord('A:A','B:B','C:J');` would also work but would take very long, since the code would also loop through empty rows

Comment: Sorry, but this is not actually what I want. I do want to use a formula and not only that, I want an ArrayFormula().