# How to use an array and a single string in the same custom function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to make a custom function that will receive an array and a string as parameters, for example:

[image]

The script so far:

```
function VISITAS(CRM,CICLO) {

  if(CRM.map){
    return CRM.map(VISITAS);
  }
  else{
    CICLO = (CICLO).toString();
   return CICLO;
  }

}
```

If i use the function like VISITAS(A1;D1) it works and return "CICLO" as needed but when using a range and a single cell, the values turns to "0" like the first image.
The script so far is a test, the second parameter will be used in some conditional operations.
How can i use a range and keep the value of the single cell?

EDIT: I'm sorry, i will provide the whole need.

This function will need to use the second parameter as a conditional to search and return data that is in another sheet and return this data for each row in the first array.

For example, i have a sheet with "CICLOS" from 1 to 7, i need it to return information of "CICLO 2" for example based on each line of the array

I have a scenario like this:

[image]

and i need to use the function one time per column using the column header and the "CLIENT" column as parameter, the output should be something like this:

[image]

With the first row below the header being the function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Supporting arrays in custom functions with multiple inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57363672/supporting-arrays-in-custom-functions-with-multiple-inputs)

Comment: One thing, the arguments for custom functions are not ranges, but rather arrays and values. Please see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#arguments.

Comment: And what exactly do you need the code to ultimately do? On the first call, `CRM` will be a 2D array and `CICLO` will be a value. And, as @anton-dementiev mentioned below, when `VISITAS` is called in the `CRM.map`, it won't know the `CICLO` value. If you could provide more detail of what you're trying to do it would help.

Comment: Can you explain what you want this function to do? You talked about what the input has to be, but didn't say anything about the output.

Comment: Hello! I'm sorry, i've edited the question and provided more detail on my need

Comment: Does it have to be a custom function, or it can be a regular Apps Script function?

Comment: It needs to pass sheets ranges as parameters and the final user who will run it, it is possible achieve this without custom function?

Comment: @IagoLosadaAlibune I updated my answer to make this a custom function, let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that:

- The parameters that you pass are (1) the array of clients, and (2) the `ciclo` to look for.
- The data to look for in another sheet is not passed as a parameter of the custom function.

If all this is correct, then, what about this:

```
function visitasCustom(clients, ciclo) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var origin = ss.getSheetByName("Origin");
  var firstRow = 2;
  var firstCol = 1;
  var numRows = origin.getLastRow() - 1;
  var numCols = 3;
  var values = origin.getRange(firstRow, firstCol, numRows, numCols).getValues();
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
    var found = false;
    for (var j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
      if (clients[i] == values[j][0] && ciclo == values[j][1]) {
        result.push(values[j][2]);
        found = true;
      }
    }
    if (!found) result.push("");
  }
  return result;
}
```

This custom function looks for data in a sheet called `Origin` and adds all the dates that correspond to that specific `Ciclo`, for each column in which you use this function.

I hope this is of any help.

Comment: Thank you! I just needed to change a little bit to concatenate results when the "CICLO" and "CLIENT" are the same, but it worked just like i needed!

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to call the 'toString()' method of something that isn't even there. When you make multiple recursive calls inside 'map()', the callback function VISITAS doesn't receive the 2nd parameter (CICLO). Since this new callback function has its own scope, CICLO is actually undefined.

The following code returns 0s:

```
function CUSTOM_FUNC(range, param) {
  if (range.map) {
    return range.map(CUSTOM_FUNC);
  } else {
    param = param.toString();
    return param;
  }
```

This snipped works correctly:

```
function CUSTOM_FUNC(range, param) {
  if (range.map) {
    return range.map(CUSTOM_FUNC);
  } else {
     range = range.toString();
    return range;
  }
```

Also, why would you use recursive calls in the first place? It's not like you have a rabbit hole in each cell containing the unspecified number of nested arrays.

Comment: Doesn't `map` send the index of the item in the array as the second parameter?

Comment: Hello Anton! Thanks for the answer, I've edited my question and provided more detail