# Apps Script Custom Formulas Optimization

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

Google provides an example of optimising a custom formula to recurse over an array where there is one.  It helps with the whole efficiency thing  The example provided from the [Apps Script Page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#optimization) shows the an example where there is 1 parameter, as:

```
function DOUBLE(input) {
  if (input.map) {            // Test whether input is an array.
    return input.map(DOUBLE); // Recurse over array if so.
  } else {
    return input * 2;
  }
}
```

What if there are 2 or more parameters? How can we still recurse?

Comment: Hi, what is the second value ? is it an array ? What exactly you want to achieve :) ? You can also read the javascript Array.map function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Supporting arrays in custom functions with multiple inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57363672/supporting-arrays-in-custom-functions-with-multiple-inputs)

Comment: I'm pretty sure @TheMaster answer covers your question entirely. Could you confirm?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your responses.  The post to which TheMaster refers is probably right, but to be honest, I don't completely understand it.  I have resolved my issue by referring back to Google's pages again.  To add further to Ghost's question, I'd like to have one parameter as an array and other other a single constant - sorry for the confusion, I'll be sure to put more thoughts into my future questions.

My updated prototype formula looks like this:

```
function DOSOMETHING(x, y) {
  return Array.isArray(x) ?
      x.map(i => i.map(cell => cell * y)) :
      x * y;
}
```

Happy to report it actually does what I want it to.  x can be a single number or an array. y can only be a single integer in this case.

Since my original post, Google updated their pages to show the function using ternary operator, which made it easier for me to read & understand.